# Photography of male with ape mask, who is the author?

Tags: nude-photography

This is a fairly known photographer I found several years ago in a compilation edited by Taschen, unfortunately I never took note of the name and now, after hours of googling, I cannot find it. The photo, indeed a hand-colored-photograph, depicts a seminude male walking towards the observer wearing what seems an ape mask or a deformed version of a human face. Another feature I remember of this photographer is a tendency to work with tattooed people as well as representation of circus and freak-shows.

Based on style, my first hint was that the author of the photographs was Jan Saudek, but I cannot find the mentioned photo in his catalogue.  Any idea of who might be the author or the name of that photo?

Although this questions seems off-topic at first, similar questions made it into this page and got positive answers:

[Who is the Japanese photographer famous for long-exposure daylight shots of busy intersections?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/30474/who-is-the-japanese-photographer-famous-for-long-exposure-daylight-shots-of-busy)
[Who is the photographer of this black and white photo of two female nudes standing over a pile of clothes?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/who-is-the-photographer-of-this-black-and-white-photo-of-two-female-nudes-standi)

Comment: Bit of a stab in the dark but it does sound like something between Wolfgang Tillmans and Nobuyoshi Araki

Comment: @Stan That needs to be an answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: @Stan Unfortunately I don't have the photo (otherwise I've done what you suggest ages ago).

Answer (score 3):

If you have the photo, you might be able to use "tineye.com" to track down various instances where it appears on the Internet (World Wide Web).

Possibly, there will be one or more instances with necessary authorship information included.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the photo (otherwise I've done what you suggest ages ago).

Comment: @je_b Yes. This was for others' benefit. I got your reply earlier.